# Best design for Category Collection

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, schema

I am developing a blog website (to practice for ReactJS).
In my website, I have a slide bar will show categories and number of posts in each category.
So, how should i design category collection?

1. Having a field named numPosts to store total posts in that category.
   And whenever i create new post document, i must increase numPost
   field in it.
2. Don't store total posts in category collection. Everytime i want to
   fetch number of posts, i have to browser post collection and count.

Is there any best design for this case?
Thank you in advance for your help!
Sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0):

This is better to count the posts (via count or $count) instead of create "numPosts" field, 
don't act like relational databases , following schema is a good one for what you want to do:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e60df95d7ff5f38b4d44d8c"),
    "nameOfCategory": "Coronavirus",
    "postsInsideThisCategory: [{
        "titleOfPost": "Is there any cure?",
        "description": "Bla Bla Bla Bla..... and Bla"
    },{
        "titleOfPost": "What is the type of coronavirus?",
        "description": "Bla Bla Bla Bla..... and Bla"
    }]
}
```

Then just use `count` or `$count` to count the number of documents inside the array of "postsInsideThisCategory" field.

Comment: So, just create one collection Category instead of 2 (Category and Post). Whenever i create new post, i will append it into "postInsideThisCategory" field. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, that's right, In this schema you will create an independent document for each category and append the posts into "postsInsideThisCategory" field for related category.

Comment: i think that way will make my schema very large. Just have few documents in category Collection (one for each collection), but each document is large and long.